# Procedure con retrazos en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

tengo el siguiente procedimiento con el cual calculo los valores de las ventas en general entre periodos determinados

```
--1. primera forma de ejecutarlo, declarando variables fijas
    declare @id_municipio numeric(18,0)= 1048
    declare @id_tercero_vendedor numeric(18,0)= NULL
    declare @fechainicial DATETIME='01-05-2019'
    declare @fechafinal DATETIME='31-05-2019'
    --AS
    BEGIN
    SET @fechainicial = @fechainicial+' 00:00:00'
        SET @fechafinal = @fechafinal+' 23:59:59'  
        /*inclusion de instruccion para dar formato de hora a las fechas*/

        SET NOCOUNT ON; 

            BEGIN 

                CREATE TABLE #informacion(
                    codigo decimal(18,0),
                    comprador varchar(max),
                    valor decimal(18,0),
                    total_abonado decimal(18,0),

                    vendedor varchar(max),
                    nro_identificacion decimal(18,0),
                    valor_iva decimal(18,0),
                    valorsubtotal decimal(18,0),
                    CantDetalle decimal(18,0),
                    CantSeries decimal(18,0)
                    )

                    insert into #informacion
                    SELECT 
                        f.codigo,
                        tc.nombre as comprador,
                        --(f.valor) valor,
                        --FORMAT(f.valor, 'N') as valor,
                        CASE f.valor
                            WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                            WHEN f.valor THEN f.valor
                        END AS valor, 
                        [dbo].[ObtenerConsignadoCredito](cre.id_credito) total_abonado,

                        ve.nombre vendedor,
                        ve.nro_identificacion,
                        (f.valor_iva) valor_iva,               
                        (f.valor - f.valor_iva) as valorsubtotal,

                        (SELECT SUM(cantidad)CONTEO1 FROM detalle_factura WHERE id_factura = f.id_factura ) AS CantDetalle,
                        (SELECT COUNT(*) CONTEO FROM factura_articulo WHERE id_factura = f.id_factura) AS CantSeries


                    FROM factura f
                            LEFT JOIN tercero ve ON ve.id_tercero = f.id_tercero_vendedor           
                            left join tercero tc on tc.id_tercero = f.id_tercero_cliente
                            left join credito cre on f.codigo = cre.codigo              
                            LEFT join municipio on municipio.id_municipio = f.id_municipio

                    WHERE  ((@fechaInicial IS NULL) OR (f.[fecha] >= @fechaInicial))
                               AND ((@fechaFinal IS NULL) OR (f.[fecha] <= @fechaFinal))       
                              AND ((@id_tercero_vendedor IS NULL)OR(F.[id_tercero_vendedor]= @id_tercero_vendedor))
                              AND ((@id_municipio IS NULL)OR(F.[id_municipio]= @id_municipio))
                    order by ve.nombre,f.fecha asc
                END

        select vendedor, nro_identificacion, sum(valorsubtotal) as valor_subtotal,sum(valor_iva) as valor_iva,sum(valor) as valor_total 
        from #informacion
        WHERE CantSeries = CantDetalle
        AND valorsubtotal != 0
        group by vendedor,nro_identificacion
        order by vendedor
        DROP TABLE #informacion
    END
```

estoy presentando un inconveniente, y es que: Cuando lo ejecuto de esta forma

```
--2. segunda forma de ejecutarlo, indicandole los parametros al procedimiento
    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [Reporte].[Ventasconsolidadas]
            @id_municipio = 1048,
            @fechainicial = N'01-05-2019',
            @fechafinal = N'31-05-2019'

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

me genera datos en 01:36 minutos, pero cuando lo executo como una consulta, me arroja los mismos datos en un tiempo estimado de 1 segundo

Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: No entiendo bien a qué te refieres cuando dices que lo ejecutas como una consulta. Por favor, explica más a detalle o pon un ejemplo.

Comment: es decir, cuando lo ejecuto de la primera forma me arroja datos en un tiempo de 1 segundo, pero cuando lo ejecuto de la segunda forma me genera los datos en 1:36 minutos

Comment: Cual es la primera forma? y cual la segunda?

Comment: El problema es que estás confundiendo al optimizador de consultas de SQL Server. Al momento de convertir la consulta en un procedimiento almacenado, se destina a generar un plan de ejecución seguro en vez de un óptimo. Gail Shaw lo explica a detalle [aquí en inglés](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/)

Comment: aun asi, cual es la pregunta o duda especifica?

Comment: @gbianchi, edite mi pregunta para especificar cual es la primera forma y cual es la segunda

Comment: @MiguelZarate, el por que tarda tanto en ahorrar los resultados al ejecutarlo de dos formas diferentes

Comment: Podrías compartir los planes de ejecución de ambas formas? Lo puedes hacer mediante esta página. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @LuisCazares observa https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ-ID8HRV

Comment: También agrega la definición de tablas e índices. Creo que te faltan varios ya que hay mucho clustered index scan. Ese plan es de la consulta directa ¿Puedes poner también el del procedimiento almacenado? ¿Viste como hay mucha diferencia entre filas estimadas y filas reales en los operadores?

Comment: Miralo https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkEq68BAV

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algo que se llama 'catch-all-query' o una consulta que abarca cualquier posibilidad. Eso evita que tengas un plan óptimo. El problema es que tu procedimiento se compiló con un mal plan de ejecución. Puedes solucionarlo usando un poco de código dinámico (pero escrito de manera correcta y segura).

```
declare @id_municipio numeric(18,0)= 1048
declare @id_tercero_vendedor numeric(18,0)= NULL
declare @fechainicial DATETIME='01-05-2019'
declare @fechafinal DATETIME='31-05-2019'
--AS

SET NOCOUNT ON; 

/*inclusion de instruccion para incluir días completos en las fechas*/
SET @fechainicial = DATEADD( DD, DATEDIFF( DD, 0, @fechainicial), 0);
SET @fechafinal = DATEADD( dd, 1, @fechafinal); --Evita la posibilidad de perder información del último minuto del día.

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Condicion NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

IF  @fechaInicial IS NOT NULL
    SET @Condicion = @Condicion + N'    AND f.[fecha] >= @fechaInicial' + CHAR(10);
IF  @fechaFinal IS NOT NULL
    SET @Condicion = @Condicion + N'    AND f.[fecha] < @fechaFinal' + CHAR(10);
IF  @id_tercero_vendedor IS NOT NULL
    SET @Condicion = @Condicion + N'    AND F.[id_tercero_vendedor] = @id_tercero_vendedor' + CHAR(10);
IF  @id_municipio IS NOT NULL
    SET @Condicion = @Condicion + N'    AND F.[id_municipio] = @id_municipio' + CHAR(10);

SET @SQL = REPLACE( N'
WITH cteinformacion AS(
    SELECT 
        f.codigo,
        tc.nombre as comprador,
        CASE f.valor
            WHEN 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN f.valor THEN f.valor
        END AS valor, 
        [dbo].[ObtenerConsignadoCredito](cre.id_credito) total_abonado,
        ve.nombre vendedor,
        ve.nro_identificacion,
        f.valor_iva AS valor_iva,               
        f.valor - f.valor_iva AS valorsubtotal,
        (SELECT SUM(cantidad)CONTEO1 FROM detalle_factura WHERE id_factura = f.id_factura ) AS CantDetalle,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) CONTEO FROM factura_articulo WHERE id_factura = f.id_factura) AS CantSeries
    FROM factura f
    LEFT JOIN tercero ve ON ve.id_tercero = f.id_tercero_vendedor           
    left join tercero tc on tc.id_tercero = f.id_tercero_cliente
    left join credito cre on f.codigo = cre.codigo              
    LEFT join municipio on municipio.id_municipio = f.id_municipio
    <<Condicion>>
)
select vendedor, nro_identificacion, sum(valorsubtotal) as valor_subtotal,sum(valor_iva) as valor_iva,sum(valor) as valor_total 
from cteinformacion
WHERE CantSeries = CantDetalle
AND valorsubtotal != 0
group by vendedor,nro_identificacion
order by vendedor;
', '<<Condicion>>', STUFF( @Condicion, 1, 7, 'WHERE') )

--Para Debug
--PRINT @SQL

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@id_municipio numeric(18,0), @id_tercero_vendedor numeric(18,0), @fechainicial DATETIME, @fechafinal DATETIME', @id_municipio, @id_tercero_vendedor, @fechainicial, @fechafinal;
```

Comment: Acepto las críticas, pero sería mejor que fueran constructivas con un comentario para aprender del error. ¿Se puede explicar el voto negativo?

Comment: Hola @Luis gracias por responder, en este caso sucede lo mismo con la consulta que me brindas

Comment: Te refieres a que hay variación según como lo realices o con esta forma también resulta lento aun siendo una consulta directa?

Comment: así es y eso es lo que no he podido comprender aun

Comment: Cual de las dos opciones que dije?

Comment: ejecute toda la instrucción que me enviaste

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94553/discussion-between-fernankin-and-luis-cazares).